# Template conversion function to const-reference

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, gcc4.9

The following works fine (as one would expect):

```
struct X {};

struct A
{
  operator X const& () 
  {
    static const X value{};
    return value; 
  }
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  X x = a;
}
```

But this is not so clear:

```
template<typename T>
struct X {};

struct A
{
  template<typename T>
  operator X<T> const& () 
  {
    static const X<T> value{};
    return value; 
  }
};

int main() 
{
  A a;
  X<int> x = a;
}
```

GCC 4.9 says `error: conversion from ‘A’ to non-scalar type ‘X<int>’ requested` whereas clang 3.4 has no problems with it.
If you remove the `const` or the `&` from the conversion function or if you write `X<int> const &x = a` then GCC is happy, too.

So GCC only fails to find the conversion function if the target type is a `const &` to a template class and you request a conversion to a non-`const &` object of that class. Is this the correct behavior? I tried to read the standard but the overloading rules are quite confusing to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug in gcc.  This is almost precisely [core DR976](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#976), the only difference being that in their example the destination type is a non-class type:

```
struct F {
   template<class T>
   operator const T&() { static T t; return t; }
};

int main() {
   F f;
   int i = f;   // ill-formed
}
```

As with your example, clang accepts and gcc rejects this example, regardless of the standard version dialect selected.

Note that the clause amended by that DR (14.8.2.3 **[temp.deduct.conv]**) does not discriminate between class and non-class destination types, so the resolution of that DR applies to your code equally.

Per the amended clause 14.8.2.3, the compiler should:

- determine `P`, the return type of the conversion function template, as `X<T> const &`, and `A`, the required result type, as `X<int>`;
- strip the reference from `P`, giving `X<T> const`;
- strip the cv-qualification from `P`, giving `X<T>`;
- deduce `T` as `int`.

I would recommend filing a bug report on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ referencing that DR.

---

Because in your case you are converting to a class type, there is a workaround available:

```
X<int> x1 = a;          // fails
X<int> x2(a);           // OK
X<int> x3 = X<int>(a);  // also OK
```

In direct-initialization, constructors of the destination type are considered (8.5p16); the default copy constructor of `X<int>` takes a parameter of type `X<int> const&`, to which as we have already seen gcc is happy to convert `a`.

Comment: Thanks to your great explanation and the link to the defect report I filed a bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61663